# Compare two list of objects and select common and difference records based some property

Tags: c#, linq

How can I compare `list A` of object type person with `list B` of person based on property `Name`, and get another `list C` containing those common in both list, and `list D` which are in `list A` but not in `list B`?

Comment: Is this a question or a tongue twister?

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = new List<int>();
var b = new List<int>();
var c = new List<int>();
var d = new List<int>();

c = a.Where(aItem => b.Any(bItem => aItem == bItem)).ToList();
d = a.Except(c).ToList();
```

You can use any logic to compare aItem to bItem.

Here are extension methods to do that.

```
public static class LinqEx
{
    public static bool DefaultCompare<T>(T one, T two)
    {
        return one.Equals(two);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Common<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
    {
        return first.Common(second, DefaultCompare);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Common<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, Func<T, T, bool> compare)
    {
        return first.Where(i1 => second.Any(i2 => compare(i1, i2)));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Common<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, out IEnumerable<T> difference)
    {
        return first.Common(second, out difference, DefaultCompare);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Common<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, out IEnumerable<T> difference, Func<T, T, bool> compare)
    {
        var common = first.Common(second, compare);

        difference = first.Except(common);

        return common;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Common<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, out List<T> difference)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> d;
        var common = first.Common(second, out d);
        difference = d.ToList();

        return common;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Common<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, out List<T> difference, Func<T, T, bool> compare)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> d;
        var common = first.Common(second, out d, compare);
        difference = d.ToList();

        return common;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<myObjectType> d;
c = a.Common(b, out d, (i1, i2) => i1.Name == i2.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is similar to the others here, but using the `Intersect()` method for the first half, which is the simplest and most *correct* way, I feel, to get the set of items that exist in both sets:

```
 var a = new[] {new Person("Alice"), new Person("Bob")};
 var b = new[] {new Person("Bob"), new Person("Charlie")};

 var inBoth = a.Intersect(b, new PersonNameEqualityComparer());
 var notInB = a.Except(b, , new PersonNameEqualityComparer());
```

`inBoth` will contain Bob, while `notInB` will contain Alice.

The only problem here is that `Intersect` needs an equality comparer that can get two Person objects and determine whether they're equal based on their Name. I wish we could just specify a lambda expression here, but until then, the implementation is simple enough:

```
class PersonNameEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
       return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is below:

```
var c = listA.Join(listB, a => a.Name, b => b.Name, (a, b) => a).ToList();
var d = listA.Except(c).ToList();
```

This will join the two lists based on the `Name` property of each object and will return the common objects from first list. The `Except()` method will return objects that are in `listA` bot not in `c`; the comparison is made using `Object.ReferenceEquals()` and the method will fail if you'll change `(a, b) => a` to `(a, b) => b`.
To avoid such scenario you'll have to implement an [`IEqualityComparer<Person>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) and pass it to the method `Except()` like this:

```
var comparer = new PersonComparer(); // the class that implements IEqualityComparer<Person>
var d = listA.Except(c, comparer).ToList();
```

Comment: I used 'Where' and 'Any' to avoid having to implement IEqualityComparer. With 'Any' you can provide a simple predicate to compare the items.

Comment: @YoryeNathan - `Where()` and `Any()` in your example have nothing to do with `IEqualityComparer`; you used those methods as a replacement of `Join()`. An implementation of `IEqualityComparer` is recomended for `Except()` method, to avoid comparison by object reference and compare by custom logic (in this case - the value of `Name` property).

Comment: Implementing IEqualityComparer for each comparing logic? Really? Any(item1 => item1.Name == item2) is a perfectly good comparing approach, and no need for a whole class to compare them by name.